# CSS3 hover opacity ease-in-out effect?

Tags: css, opacity, fade

Is there any better and simpler way writing opacity ease-in-out effect below?

CSS:

```
 .button-hover {
    font-family: arial black;
    font-size: 100px;
    color: #000;

    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    opacity: 1;
}

.button-hover:hover {
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

As you can see that I repeat these lines twice which does not seem ideal:

```
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <a href="#" class="button-hover">HOVER ME</a>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pmjw7zeu/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Don't repeat the transition rules.** [CSS pre-processors](https://css-tricks.com/sass-vs-less/) can help with the vendor prefixing but you really don't need to (and shouldn't) repeat the transition declarations in the `:hover`. Just set them *once* in elements's default state like so:

```css
.button-hover {
    font-family: arial black;
    font-size: 100px;
    color: #000;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    opacity: 1;
}

.button-hover:hover {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <a href="#" class="button-hover">HOVER ME</a>
</div>
```

[Understanding CSS3 Transitions](http://alistapart.com/article/understanding-css3-transitions)

Comment: Good answer! You should only declare them if they are different.

Answer (score 3):

**[SASS](http://sass-lang.com/guide)** & **[LESS](http://lesscss.org/)** can make this easy for you. You can use **SASS & LESS Mixins** for this.

**Example (SASS):**

```
/* Create a Mixin (SASS) */
@mixin transition($property, $time, $method) {
  -webkit-transition: $property $time $method;
  -moz-transition: $property $time $method;
  -ms-transition: $property $time $method;
  -o-transition: $property $time $method;
  transition: $property $time $method;
}

/* Include this Mixin (SASS) */
.button-hover:hover {
  @include transition(opacity, 1s, ease-in-out);
}
```

**Example (LESS):**

```
/* Create a Mixin (LESS) */
.transition(@property, @time, @method) {
  -webkit-transition: @arguments;
  -moz-transition: @arguments;
  -ms-transition: @arguments;
  -o-transition: @arguments;
  transition: @arguments;
}

/* Include this Mixin (LESS) */
.button-hover:hover {
  .transition(opacity, 1s, ease-in-out);
}
```

This will convert into **CSS**:

```
.button-hover:hover {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

More about **[SASS](http://sass-lang.com)**, **[LESS](http://lesscss.org/)**

Comment: but i use LESS.

Comment: @teelou I've integrated the `less` mixin as well, please have a look. This is much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Those are prefixes needed for browser support.
You can see [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions) which browsers versions needs a prefix and decide if you can delete them based on what browsers you want to support.

For example the `-moz-` prefix is for Firefox and you can see that from Firefox 16 it is not needed anymore, so you can use `transition` without `-moz-` for Firefox 16+.

Read more about prefixes [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix).